# How to override gradient color parameter of Container widget with color parameter

Tags: flutter, colors, containers, linear-gradients

I have used `gradient` parameter of a `Container` widget which shows gradient color only if the condition is true if not gradient color is transparent.

Excepted Output : -

If the condition is false then `Container` widget could be colored by the color passed in the `color` parameter. In the below code, it is green.

Excepted Output Image : -

[image]

Actual Output : -

Transparent gradient color overrides the color given to the `color` parameter

Actual Output Image : -

[image]

**Note** : - **`color` parameter can have different colors since it also depends on some Boolean flags hence setting the same color to the `gradient` parameter won't work.**

Code : -

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(const ExampleApp());

class ExampleApp extends StatefulWidget {
  const ExampleApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<ExampleApp> createState() => _ExampleAppState();
}

class _ExampleAppState extends State<ExampleApp> {
  bool showGradient = false;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
          body: Center(
        child: Container(
          decoration: BoxDecoration(
              gradient: LinearGradient(colors: [
                showGradient ? Colors.blue : Colors.transparent,
                showGradient ? Colors.orange : Colors.transparent,
              ]),
              color: Colors.green[100],
              border: Border.all()),
          height: 100,
          width: 100,
        ),
      )),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try instead of

```
          gradient: LinearGradient(colors: [
            showGradient ? Colors.blue : Colors.transparent,
            showGradient ? Colors.orange : Colors.transparent,
          ]),
```

do

```
          gradient: showGradient ? LinearGradient(colors: [
            Colors.blue,
            Colors.orange
          ]) : null,
```

Answer (score 1):

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(const ExampleApp());

class ExampleApp extends StatefulWidget {
  const ExampleApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<ExampleApp> createState() => _ExampleAppState();
}

class _ExampleAppState extends State<ExampleApp> {
  bool showGradient = false;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
          body: Center(
        child: Container(
          decoration: BoxDecoration(
              gradient: showGradient ? const LinearGradient(colors: [Colors.blue, Colors.orange]) : null,
              color: Colors.green,
              border: Border.all()),
          height: 100,
          width: 100,
        ),
      )),
    );
  }
}
```